# Property 'withLatestFrom' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Tags: angular, redux, observable, ngrx-effects

I was creating an angular library from my older code, so I created a new library project using **generate-angular2-library**. Then I encountered this error

this is my Effects Code --

```
    @Effect() addProduct$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(spsCart.CART_ADD_PRODUCT)
    .map(toPayload)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$) // -------- **ERROR OCCURES HERE**
    .switchMap(([payload, storeState]) => {
      -- MY CODE 
    });
```

This is my package.json --

```
    "devDependencies": {
"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "4.4.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
"@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.2",
"codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
"concurrently": "^3.4.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"del": "^2.2.2",
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
"gulp-rollup": "^2.15.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"lite-server": "^2.3.0",
"node-sass": "^4.5.2",
"node-sass-tilde-importer": "^1.0.0",
"node-watch": "^0.5.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"rollup": "^0.49.3",
"run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
"rxjs": "^5.4.3",
"systemjs": "^0.20.12",
"ts-node": "~3.2.0",
"tslint": "~5.7.0",
"typescript": "~2.4.2",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
 },
 "engines": {
   "node": ">=6.0.0"
 },
   "dependencies": {
    "@ngrx/effects": "^4.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^4.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^4.1.1"
   }
```

I Am not Sure if i am getting this error because of Version Upgrade. Or I am Doing Something Wrong. Can you Please Help? Thanks in Advance

Comment: As for any other rxjs operator, you must import it: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/withLatestFrom';`

Comment: Do you have `import 'rxjs/add/operator/withLatestFrom';` ?

Comment: this issue is solved, i was not adding operators as defined.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is solved, the problem was due to rxjs upgrade.